# Remove Trailing \ in subst Command

Tags: windows, batch-file, variable-expansion

I have added a command to my Context Menu via the Registry in HKCR\Drive\shell\MapLocalDriveHere\command such that when I right click a drive. I'd like it to give me the name of the drive that I have right-clicked as "C:" not "C:\", as this causes problems with the command I'm trying to run.

```
cmd /c subst %1 /D
```

This expands to:

```
cmd /c subst C:\ /D
```

And the command fails (it expects `subst C: /D`). How do I get the parameter without the trailing \, or remove it? `%~d1` and `%~1` don't expand from the registry key, type REG_EXPAND_SZ.

You can understand better what I'm trying to do by viewing the source of the project, located at https://github.com/Ehryk/ContextMenuTools (especially this file: https://github.com/Ehryk/ContextMenuTools/blob/master/Custom%20Installs/Map%20Local%20Drive%20Here/MapLocalDriveHere.inf )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, I had to switch to `%V` instead of `%1` to resolve this in the registry:

```
cmd /c mapdrive.bat ""%V"" /D

HKCR,Drive\Shell\MapLocalDriveHere\command,,0x00020000,"cmd /c mapdrive.bat ""%V"" /D"
```

Answer (score 5):

You get in a `for /f` loop with the `%%~d` parameter the drive letter with a colon:

```
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN ("%~1") DO cmd /c subst %%~da /D
```

Comment: it can be done even with plain for: `for %%d in ("%~1") do cmd /c subst %%~da /D`

Comment: `%~1` doesn't expand from the registry key. This is in a registry key in HKCR\Drive\shell\MapLocalDriveHere\command, Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ

Comment: If you make a question, provide all relevant data. In a Regkey you can use `%1` without double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Well... Let's combine the best features of captcha's and npocmaka's answers. There is no need for an intermediate variable, nor is there a need for a FOR statement:

```
cmd /c subst %~d1 /D
```

Comment: `%~d1` doesn't expand, nor does `%~1`. So far only `%1` becomes `{Drive}:\`. This is in a registry key in HKCR\Drive\shell\MapLocalDriveHere\command, Type: REG_EXPAND_SZ

Answer (score 2):

```
set "param=%~1"
set "param=%param:~0,-1%"
cmd /c subst %param% /D
```

Comment: I'd add a check `if "%param:~-1%"=="\"` to be on the safe side.

Comment: I don't think I can do multiple lines in the registry key. Perhaps I need to call a .bat file that does this instead of attempting to do it with a one liner?

Comment: you can add new line to a registry key.You need to edit it in binary mode and set the hex value for a new line - `0d 0a `

Comment: or you can just set `&` between the lines

Comment: `%~1` does not expand, and I don't know if I can do parameter manipulations in registry keys like you can in .bat files (it doesn't seem to be working)